# column size in TableLayoutPanel keeps changing in designer

Tags: c#, resize, designer, tablelayoutpanel

I added a tableLayoutPanel to my user control.

```
It is not docked or anchored.
It has 4 columns and 4 rows.
The items within each cell are docked fully within each cell.
```

The size settings for the columns are as follows.

```
-Column 1 - Percent - 100%
-Column 2 - Absolute - 25
-Column 3 - Absolute - 35
-Column 4 - Absolute - 25
```

As I understand it the absolute values should always remain the correct size and then column 1 should take up the rest of the space.

When I initially create the control everything looks fine. Ill go back to coding some other area of my program doesn't mater what, and at some point ill return to the designer where my tableLayoutPanel is and the fourth column will be larger then before. So I have to open up the Column and Row Styles editor and change the size Column for back to 25.

How can I get these settings to stick? It is driving me crazy!

As Requested here is my designer code.

```
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.OutsetDouble;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 35F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 25F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label8, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnStartingUp, 3, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.txtOffset, 2, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnDurationUp, 3, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label10, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnFrequencyUp, 3, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.txtFrequency, 2, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnPowerUp, 3, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label9, 0, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.txtLaserPower, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label7, 0, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnPowerDown, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnFrequencyDown, 1, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnDurationDown, 1, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.btnOffsetDown, 1, 3);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.txtDuration, 2, 2);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(61, 610);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 98);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 4;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 21F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 21F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 21F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 21F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 98);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 168;
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it.  Please post some code that does.

Comment: I did everything in the designer and It can happen without me even running my code. So I can post my designer code. As a test I went to the forms constructor typed some jibberish and deleted it went back to the designer and saw that it was slightly bigger... again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I was able to duplicate the problem once I placed labels in the TableLayoutPanel.

When the Label's `AutoSize=true` were set, it seemed to cause the column resize problem.

When I changed all of the Label's `AutoSize=false`, the problem went away, and the column sizes stayed the same.

The TextBoxes also interfere because they have an AutoSize property (not visible in designer or from code) to control the height of the control.  Setting the Textbox `MultiLine=true` did not help.

Creating my own TextBox where I specifically set the `AutoSize=false` fixed the problem:

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox {
  public TextBoxEx() {
    this.AutoSize = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't seem to help. =( Many of the times i go back to my user control and the last column is slightly bigger. there's got to be some silly setting that Im missing.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out my user control that hosts the TableLayoutPanel had "AutoScaleMode" set to "Font" when I changed it to "None" the problem has seemed to gone away. Im going to give it a little time before I decide that its the solution.   Thanks for you help!

Comment: @hrh It's also the `TextBoxes`, which have a default AutoSize on the height property (property is hidden from you).  That also is causing the problem.

Comment: ok ill change that too, I looked for the property but since it was hidden I assumed there was none.

Comment: @hrh That's why I updated my answer to include a custom `TextBox`.  Good luck.